# How to add items onto an existing list on a POJO

Tags: java

I have a POJO similar to this

```
public class Color {
  public List<Shade> shades = new ArrayList();

  public setShades (List<Shade> shades) {this.shades = shades;}
  public List<Shade> getShades() {return this.shades;}
}
```

This way I can only add the shades by a list. Meaning I can only do:

```
Color myColor = new Color();
List<Shade> myShades = new ArrayList();
myShades.add(new Shade("light"));
myColor.setShades(myShades);
```

However, I want to be able to add directly to the list of shades that are already set. Something like this:

```
Color myFinalColor = new Color();
for (Color c : myColorList) {
  for (Shade s : myShade) {
    if (!("dark").equalsIgnoreCase(s.getName()))
       myFinalColor.addToShadeList(s); //This will add to the existing shade list. 
  }
}
```

I can do something like this to achieve what I want but it seems cumbersome.

```
Color myFinalColor = new Color();
for (Color c : myColorList) {
  for (Shade s : myShade) {
    if (!("dark").equalsIgnoreCase(s.getName())) {
       List<Shade> existingShades = myFinalColor.getShades();
       existingShades.add(s);
       myFinalColor.setShades(existingShades); 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you just do it like that:

```
myFinalColor.getShades().add(s);
```

or just add `addShade` method to Color class like this:

```
public void addShade(Shade shade) {
    shades.add(shade);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as

```
Color myFinalColor = new Color();
List<Shade> existingShades = myFinalColor.getShades();
for (Shade s : myShade)
   if (!"dark".equalsIgnoreCase(s.getName()))
       existingShades.add(s);
```